# Django Rest-Framework Token Authentication not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create simple signup, login and logout page. When I enter details of signup in Postman it is working I checked on admin page but when logging in it always says Invalid credentials.

These are all the codes I have written:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'app',
    'rest_framework',    
]
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, permissions, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from .serializers import UserSerializer, UserLoginSerializer
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
class UserRegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

class UserLoginView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.validated_data.get('user')
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
                return Response({'token': token.key, 'message': 'Login successful'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            print(serializer.errors)
        return Response({'message': 'Invalid credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)


class UserLogoutView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        return Response({'message': 'Logout successful'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

How can I solve the error?

Output in Postman:

```
{
    "message": "Invalid credentials"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be trying to get validated "user" from serializer but you are using UserLoginSerializer that only include "username" and "password"

Also, [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) states that login() method works when you have an authenticated user you want to attach to the current session. For your case, you might use authenticate() to verify the user credentials from the request.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

if user:
    username = serializer.validated_data.get('username')
    password = serializer.validated_data.get('password')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a view in order to obtain the token, you can just simply use this view from the `rest_framework` itself:

```py
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('obtain-auth-token/', obtain_auth_token, name='obtain-auth-token'),
    ...
]
```

You can read the docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication).
Also, you can use [JWT Authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#json-web-token-authentication).